# C#: Visual Studio 2019: Error doesn't get catched

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Variable that gets filled by reading from a JSON. If the value isn't set in the JSON, the value is null. I surrounded the part where I need to use the value, so if it is null, nothing interrupts the program:

```
try
{
    settings.DefaultKomaxPath = settings.DefaultKomaxPath.Replace("{oldname}", oldName);
    settings.DefaultKomaxPath = settings.DefaultKomaxPath.Replace("{username}", username);
    settings.ExcelPath_KomaxListe = settings.DefaultKomaxPath;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"\"DefaultKomaxPath\" seems not to be set in \"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\assets\\settings\\DefaultSettings.json\"");
    CloseApp();
}
```

Now `string.Replace` throws a `NullReferenceException, when my string is null`, but instead of getting caught, VS shows me where the error gets thrown:

[image]

When I execute the program normally, without VS, the error gets caught, but when I debug, this happens. I tried Code cleaning, Restarting, etc.

Comment: That is a feature. In the popup that shows the error, you can uncheck break when this exception is thrown checkbox to not to break when exception is thrown. VS is just stopping to show you the place where exception is thrown, if you continue the execution it will then enter the catch block.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I don't know why that got turned on

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn, Is it possible for you to provide the specific DefaultKomaxPath string ? It may help me to reproduce your problem better.

Comment: At the moment, I placed it on `C:/KomaxExcel.xlsm`

Comment: Sorry for the late update, based on my test, I think your DefaultKomaxPath string should have "{oldname}" or "{username}", but I didn't these two string in the the specific DefaultKomaxPath string. Therefore, I think it can not be replaced.